# Single Serialization Type (SST) of Pig/Cascading versus Multiple Serialization Type (MST) of Apache Crunch

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cascading, hadoop2, apache-crunch

In their FAQ here, Crunch teams highlights the main difference to be MST of Crunch over SST of Cascading. I am not sure how these are different. Can some one explain with an example?